# How to hide the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the HTML page

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, hide

I have this nasty horizontal scroll bar at the very bottom of my HTML page:

[image: Naughty horizontal scroll bar]

I tried this so far:

```
body {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but no luck.

You can see the entire page implementation [here](https://github.com/coderodde/coderodde.github.io/blob/master/weblog/index.html). Also, you can view the page in action [here](http://coderodde.github.io/weblog/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in `body`. It is in your `div` which has the `id="main"`.

You added `overflow-x: scroll;` there. There are two solutions for this

In your `#main {}` CSS:

**Solution 1: If you want to add scroll on content overflow**
If you don't want to scroll initially but when the content overflow you want a scroll there then you can change `overflow-x: scroll;` to `overflow-x: auto;`

**Solution 2: If you don't want to add scroll at all**
If you don't want to have a scroll in any case then you can change `overflow-x: scroll;` to `overflow-x: hidden;`

See developers mode for reference.
[image: Image with no overflow example]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `max-width:100vw;` in your body.
This makes the maximum width of your body 100% of your screen size.

```
body{
    max-width:100vw;
}
```